# Rstudio crashing when using filter()

Tags: r, rstudio

## Problem

RStudio keeps crashing when I use this code tutorial from '[R for Data Science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html)':

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

filter(flights, month == 1, day == 1).
```

I would appreciate it if anyone knows how I can solve this.

When I run RStudio via anaconda-navigator from the terminal, I get the following error message (home directory edited to ~ for privacy):

```
~/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/rstudio.sh: line 3: 19137 Segmentation fault
~/anaconda3/bin/rstudio > ~/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/rstudio-out-1.txt 
~/.anaconda/navigator/scripts/rstudio-err-1.txt
```

I'm new to R, but have some background in python, so I have tried the following:

- RStudio presents and reads the 'flights' dataframe without problems.
- Assigning the filter to an object (`jan1 <- filter(flights, month == 1, day == 1)`) works, but calling the object `jan1` then crashes RStudio again.
- filtering only by `month` or `day` alone causes no problems.
- I can perform this task using the R interpreter on the terminal without problem.

I am using RStudio v1.1.383, installed using conda 4.4.11, on Linux Mint - Linux version 4.4.0-92-generic (buildd@lcy01-17) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4).

Comment: It all works if you don't use Anaconda.  But with `conda` you end up mixing differernt shared libraries and compilation settings and bad things happen.

Comment: Thank you for that. I loaded RStudio directly from the terminal, rather than via anaconda, and got this error: `load glyph failed err=6 face=0x55f0ba7b0980, glyph=2798
load glyph failed err=6 face=0x55f0ba7b0980, glyph=2798
Segmentation fault
`

Comment: If you want privacy, you missed one `/home/` in your second line.

Comment: If I were you, I would uninstall Anaconda and won't get near it ever again. Fresh install of R/RStudio should work once that thing removed

Comment: Thank you Gregor - duly edited.

Comment: David, thanks for that too. Is Anaconda really so bad? I'm not exactly wedded to it, but it has been useful when I was working in python. I'll give it a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Anaconda is an overkill that introduces little convenience (if any) in exchange of a huge headache when something breaks. And when it comes to R- it always breaks. Re- Python / Jupyter, Anaconda adds absolutely nothing. Installing Python is straight forward (it even adds the path to your env vars) and installing Jupyter from python is as simple as `pip3 install jupyter` (seriously, can it get any simpler?). I can't think of a single good reason of installing that huge pile on needless packages/IDEs/dependencies/other useless things called Anaconda.

Comment: Jupyter is also part of Debian and hence Mint (at possibly an older version).

Comment: Agreed on anaconda. If you want to play with reproducible environment for your R development, official Rocker images for Docker (R+Rstudio server) might be a better solution: https://hub.docker.com/r/rocker/rstudio/